# unsigned bytes in Java byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, unsigned

This may seem like an easy question, but I'm so confused.

```
byte[] bArray = new byte[]{(byte) (0x80 & 0xff)};
System.out.println(bArray[0]);
```

and my output is -128. Why?
How can I rewrite this so that the byte array contains 128?
I thought that the `0xff` made it unsigned.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You put the result into a byte. All Java bytes are signed. You could convert it to an int after reading it from the byte array.

Answer (score 9):

> I thought that the 0xff made it unsigned.

Well, it does, sort of - it promotes it to an `int`, and keeps just the last 8 bits.

However, you're then casting the result of that back to a `byte`, and a `byte` in Java is *always* signed. (It's annoying, but it's the way it is.)  So you might as well just have written:

```
byte[] bArray = { (byte) 0x80 };
```

The result would be exactly the same.

You're storing the bit pattern you want to store (10000000) so if you're transmitting this elsewhere, you don't need to worry... it's just when you're viewing it as a `byte` in Java that it's annoying.

Comment: Is there a way to write it so that the byte array contains 128 and not -128?

Comment: @namsayin: No, because 128 is out of the range of a byte, because bytes are signed... You will never get a `byte` in Java that's not in the range -128 to 127 inclusive.

Comment: @namsayin bytevalue 0 is basically 128 if it was unsigned

Comment: @namsayin: there is no such byte as `128` and no way to store it in any kind of holder of bytes.

Comment: Did you think to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#MAX_VALUE or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1 or even https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html?

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow! Thanks. I always thought that the bytevalue -128 represents the unsigned bytevalue 0 until it reaches 127 which is equal to 255 if it was unsigned. You live and learn.

Answer (score 3):

Value range of byte according [Java Language Specification 4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

> For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive

so there is no way (in Java) that a byte will hold (byte) 128.

You can cast the byte to an int and apply `& 0xff` to get the unsigned representation of the byte (as an int). But if you cast it back to an byte it will again be interpreted as being a signed value between -128 and 127...

If you are only concerned with printing:

```
System.out.println(bArray[0] & 0xff);
```

or, for hexadecimal

```
System.out.printf("0x%02x\n", bArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer is attached in the big picture [image]

Comment: as you can see the max. value is 127, so if you want 128 you need to upgrade to short type instead of byte type.